# decoding a Byte Array sent from arduino to TCP Server made with Python

Tags: python, utf-8, arduino, tcpclient

I am converting sensor data to byte and writing a byte array from an arduino to a TCP server made with Python, but somehow the sensor data which are in the array triggers variations of the UTF-8 errors displayed below when decoded.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 1: invalid continuation byte`

Where "0xcf" and "0xff" change from error to error.

I suspect this is because the sensor data can sometimes be negative values. I know a byte cannot hold a negative number and UTF-8 can do 0-256. I think I must send a dedicated "-" sign before the negative values. However, I cannot predict when the negative values occur. Therefore, there must be a better way of doing this. I am able to send the array of bytes without decoding it, but I suspect there are some problems here as well because the two first positions should hold different values than the remaining 6 positions, as shown below:
`b'\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

My question is: how can I send negative values as byte and decode it correctly.

For context I will attach my code.
Arduino Client:
`

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "AK09918.h"
#include "ICM20600.h"
#include <Wire.h>
//----------------------------------

//tiltsensor
AK09918_err_type_t err;
int32_t x, y, z;
AK09918 ak09918;
ICM20600 icm20600(true);
int16_t acc_x, acc_y, acc_z;
int32_t offset_x, offset_y, offset_z;
double roll, pitch;
//----------------------------------

//Ethernet
byte mac[] = { 0xBE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //not important if only one ethernet shield
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, X, X}; //IP of this arduino unit
byte server[] = { 192, 168, X, X}; //IP of server you want to contact
int tcp_port = 65432; // a nice port to send/acess the information on
EthernetClient client; 
//----------------------------------

//byte array
byte array[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
//----------------------------------

void setup()
{
  //tiltsensor
  Wire.begin();
  err = ak09918.initialize();
  icm20600.initialize();
  ak09918.switchMode(AK09918_POWER_DOWN);
  ak09918.switchMode(AK09918_CONTINUOUS_100HZ);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  err = ak09918.isDataReady();
  while (err != AK09918_ERR_OK) {
      Serial.println("Waiting Sensor");
      delay(100);
      err = ak09918.isDataReady();}
  Serial.println("Start figure-8 calibration after 2 seconds.");
  delay(2000);
  //calibrate(10000, &offset_x, &offset_y, &offset_z);
  Serial.println("");
  //----------------------------------

  //Ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  if (client.connect(server, tcp_port)) { // Connection to server
    Serial.println("Connected to server.js");
    client.println();} 
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");}
  //----------------------------------
}

void loop()
{
  //tiltsensor
  acc_x = icm20600.getAccelerationX();
  acc_y = icm20600.getAccelerationY();
  acc_z = icm20600.getAccelerationZ();
  roll = atan2((float)acc_y, (float)acc_z) * 57.3;
  pitch = atan2(-(float)acc_x, sqrt((float)acc_y * acc_y + (float)acc_z * acc_z)) * 57.3;
  //----------------------------------

  //bytearray
  array[0] = byte(roll);
  array[1] = byte(pitch);
  //----------------------------------

  //test
  Serial.write(array, 8);
  Serial.println();
  delay(500); 
  //----------------------------------


  //Ethernet
  if (client.available()) {
      //client.print(array);
      //client.write(array[0]);
      client.write(array, 8);
      //client.write(array, 8);//((uint8_t*) array, sizeof(array));
      delay(3000); 
    }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
  //----------------------------------
}
```

`

TCP server (python):

`

```
# echo-server.py
import time
import socket

HOST = "192.168.X.X"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            #msg = s.recv(1024)
            #print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
            print(data.decode("utf-8"))
            #time.sleep(3)
            #conn.sendall(data)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.send(data)
```

`

I am able to establish a connection to the server and the client can write to it.
However, I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 0: invalid start byte` type errors.

Comment: "I am converting sensor data to byte and writing a byte array from", you didn't *converting* the data to byte and writing to a byte array with `array[0] = byte(roll);`,  you *truncated* a `double`(which is 4-byte long in Arduino) to a single byte. To send the value of `roll` as bytes, it should be `Serial.write(&roll, 4)`.

Comment: To your python error, the Arduino isn't encoding the data in UTF-8, it is sent as raw binary (i.e. byte), therefore there is no need to do decoding with `msg.decode("utf-8")`.

Comment: @hcheung First off, thank you so much for your help. I see now that I do not need to decode the input to the server. My goal is to send a byte or HEX array and read it back on the server. So I want to send the entire array and not single variables. Can `(&roll, 4)` be integrated in the byte array?

Comment: The array in your code is so-called "through-away" variable, meaning that it is only used once, therefore there is no need to create an array. You can achieve it with `Serial.write(&roll, 4)` followed by `Serial.wirte(&pitch,4)`, it will send total of 8 bytes as sending an array of 8 bytes. However, if you really want to send an copy of roll and pitch as an array, you need to copy the data to the array first with `memcpy(array, &roll, 4);` and `memcpy(array+4, &pitch, 4);`, you can read more about [memcpy](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make some progress,

for Arduino:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "AK09918.h"
#include "ICM20600.h"
#include <Wire.h>
//----------------------------------

//tiltsensor
AK09918_err_type_t err;
int32_t x, y, z;
AK09918 ak09918;
ICM20600 icm20600(true);
int16_t acc_x, acc_y, acc_z;
int32_t offset_x, offset_y, offset_z;
double roll, pitch;
//----------------------------------

//Ethernet
byte mac[] = { 0xBE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //not important if only one ethernet shield
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, X, XX}; //IP of this arduino unit
byte server[] = { 192, 168, X, XX}; //IP of server you want to contact
int tcp_port = 65432; // a nice port to send/acess the information on
EthernetClient client; 
//----------------------------------


//byte array
union some_data{  //convert a float to 4 bytes
  float tobytes;
  byte bytearray[4];
};

byte array[14] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //intial array
//----------------------------------

void setup()
{
  //tiltsensor
  Wire.begin();
  err = ak09918.initialize();
  icm20600.initialize();
  ak09918.switchMode(AK09918_POWER_DOWN);
  ak09918.switchMode(AK09918_CONTINUOUS_100HZ);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  err = ak09918.isDataReady();
  while (err != AK09918_ERR_OK) {
      Serial.println("Waiting Sensor");
      delay(100);
      err = ak09918.isDataReady();}
  Serial.println("Start figure-8 calibration after 2 seconds.");
  delay(2000);
  //calibrate(10000, &offset_x, &offset_y, &offset_z);
  Serial.println("");
  //----------------------------------

  //Ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  if (client.connect(server, tcp_port)) { // Connection to server
    Serial.println("Connected to server.js");
    client.println();} 
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");}
  //----------------------------------

  //byte array

  //----------------------------------
}

void loop()
{
  //tiltsensor
  acc_x = icm20600.getAccelerationX();
  acc_y = icm20600.getAccelerationY();
  acc_z = icm20600.getAccelerationZ();
  roll = atan2((float)acc_y, (float)acc_z) * 57.3;
  pitch = atan2(-(float)acc_x, sqrt((float)acc_y * acc_y + (float)acc_z * acc_z)) * 57.3;
  //----------------------------------


  //bytearray
   if (roll < 0) {array[0] = 0;}  //put identifier for positive or negative value in specific posision in byte array
  else {array[0] = 1;}

  if (pitch < 0) {array[5] = 0;} // same for second sensor value
  else {array[5] = 1;}

  union some_data sensor1;  //use the union function separately
  union some_data sensor2;

  sensor1.tobytes =abs(roll); //get byte array for sensor value
  sensor2.tobytes =abs(pitch); //get byte array for sensor value

  for (int i=0; i<sizeof sensor1.bytearray/sizeof sensor1.bytearray[0]; i++) {   //put sensor value byte array into main byte array
    array[1+i] =  sensor1.bytearray[i];
    array[6+i] =  sensor2.bytearray[i];
    }
  //----------------------------------

  //test
  Serial.write(array, sizeof array);
  Serial.println();
  delay(500); 
  //----------------------------------


  //Ethernet
  if (client.available()) {
      //client.print(array);
      //client.write(array[0]);
      client.write(array, sizeof array);
      //client.write(array, 8);//((uint8_t*) array, sizeof(array));
      delay(3000); 
    }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
  //----------------------------------
}
```

For python TCP Server.

```
# echo-server.py
import time
import socket

HOST = "192.168.XX.XX"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            #msg = s.recv(1024)
            #print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
            print(data)#.decode("utf-8"))
            #time.sleep(3)
            #conn.sendall(data)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.send(data)
```

Comment: Hi! This looks more like an edit to the question, than an answer. The best way is usually to update it and to add a section below, describing the changes. Additionally, I would suggest you start from a simple minimal example: an Arduino script that continuously writes fixed values (of say -1.5, +1e8)  and a python code, that is able to recover these specific values.

Answer (score 0):

As @hcheung mentioned in the comment, in the Arduino side you can simply use

```
Serial.write(&roll, 4);
Serial.wirte(&pitch,4);
```

The sign is already encoded in these bytes as the first bits. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#:%7E:text=The%20bits%20are%20laid%20out%20as%20follows) for example.

On your python side, I would suggest you look into the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/struct.html)

For your specific case just use

```py
roll, pitch = struct.unpack("dd", data)
```

where `"dd"` describes your format of two `d`oubles.